# Smarty dynamic error list

Tags: php, smarty

Im new to Smarty in combination with PHP and I really like it. 
Unfortunatly im running into a problem while validating fields after a $_POST has been done.

I've made an array called $errors and use that to save error messages in, for example: $errors[] .= "Wrong email";. 
My problem is in sending the $errors array over to the template so I can use it to display the error messages.

My question: How do you 'transfer' the $errors variable over to the template file so you can use it there with, for example {foreach}. I was planning on doing something like

```
{if $hasErrors} 
    {foreach from=errors item=error}
          <li>{$error}</li>
    {/foreach}
{/if}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign arrays to your template like you can any other variable.

```
$smarty->assign('errors', $errors);
```

Also, when building your array initially, drop the concatenation operator and just use:

```
$errors[] = 'Wrong email';
```

Finally, be sure to initialize your array before attempting to add elements to it, or assigning it.

```
$errors = array()
```

---

**EDIT:** Now that you've included the additional information, I think the problem has to do with your Smarty tag syntax.  Try this line instead, adding a `$` to your variable:

```
{foreach from=$errors item=error}
```